# Uniformly convergence(sequence of the functions) - integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

## $f(x)$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{[2^nx]-2[2^{n-1}x]}{3^n}$ then,  $\int_0^1 f(x)dx $ =???

Here is my attempt

Let the $g_n(x)=\frac{[2^nx]-2[2^{n-1}x]}{3^n}$ for convienience.

Then, when we think about the $\forall x \in [\frac{m}{2^{n-1}}, \frac{m+1}{2^{n-1}})$ for integer $m$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ < $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n}$

By Weirestrass  M- test, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_n(x)$ is uniformly converge.

Hence, $\int\sum g_n = \sum\int g $

So All I have to do is Just Calculating $\int_0^1 g_n(x)dx $.

But I've stuck when Calculate those integration please help me.

(plus, If there are some error in my attempt, It would be thanksful that correction that I was wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: To calculate the integral $\int_0^1 g_n(x)\,dx$, try first to write $g_n(x)$ for every interval $[\frac{2m}{2^n},\frac{2m+1}{2^n})$ and $[\frac{2m+1}{2^n},\frac{2m+2}{2^n})$.